# What Characters Are These?

Tags: character-encoding

I have some Chinese text in my MYSQL database. And when I export, I am getting random strings of gibberish despite outputting as UTF-8. I can't figure out the problem because I don't know what this character set is called. Can someone help identify what this string of random characters below is?

ç¼™äº‘çƒ§é¥¼

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the string `\u7f19\u4e91\u70e7\u997c` (缙云烧饼) encoded in UTF-8 (as the bytes `E7 BC 99 E4 BA 91 E7 83 A7 E9 A5 BC`) but misinterpreted as Windows-1252.

Comment: Can I ask how you converted what I had above to \u7f19\u4e91\u70e7\u997c and E7 BC 99 E4 BA 91 E7 83 A7 E9 A5 BC ? What tool did you use?

Comment: I just saved it in Notepad++ in “ANSI” encoding, and when I re-opened it, it automatically got detected as UTF-8.